# Deformed leaves on Buddha Hand citron

Tags: diseases, citrus

What citrus disease is this?

I picked up the very last Buddha Hand Citron from the store, so I couldn’t choose a better looking plant. Its leaves have wavy contours and the inside is bubbly.

I don’t see any pests on it. I’ve looked underneath the leaves. I’ve checked for wiggly routes by leaf miners. Haven’t found anything of that sort.

Topside
[image]

Bottom side
[image]

Whole tree
[image]